# Embedding an image in Shiny App; unable to successfully show image

Tags: r, image, shiny, embed

I am trying to build a shiny app with a feature in it that embeds an image. This is my first time doing it so of course it is not working properly. Here is some code which shows what I am trying to do:-

```
ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Example title'),
  tabsetPanel(
    
    tabPanel("example ui",

             sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                          dateInput("daterange_process", "Select date", value = "2021-11-01")),
             
             mainPanel(column(width = 10,h4("Process map"),
                              tags$img(src="processmapexample.png", height ="200px", width="300px", 
                                       alt="something went wrong", deleteFile=FALSE)))
             
             
             
             
             
             #)#end of sidebarlayout
    )#end of tabpanel
  )#end of tabset panel
)#end of fluidpage/UI




server<-function(input,output,session){
  options(scipen=999)

  rv <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observe({

    
  })#end of observe
  
}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

And this is the outcome:-

[image]

The image that I am trying to embed is in a folder called "www" in the directory along with the app. The path is as follows:-

```
| Documents
   | testapp
      | app.R
      | www
          | processmapexample.png
```

I have a feeling that I have not specified or set up the directory in a right way. Can anyone advise on what I should do?

Comment: Try to add the directory using shiny function `addResourcePath`

Comment: Your code works fine with an image in my www folder.

Comment: @YBS on my end the code does not work yet. Image is in the ```www``` folder as well

Comment: Does ```addResourcePath``` go in the ui or the server?